# jbpm process terminating web instances

Tags: java, spring, drools

I am using drools version 5.3.0, while processing the transactions the Tomcat container stopped working. Below is the loading error message.
Please help what could be the reason for the error?

`org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. 
Could not load [org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeFactoryServiceImpl]. 
The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal Access: this web application instance has beem stopped already. 
Could not load [org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeFactoryServiceImpl]. 
The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.webappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading (WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1435) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1423)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1262) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.webappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.newInstance(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.call(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:202) 
at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl.get(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:159).
at org.drools.runtime.process. ProcessRuntimeFactory.loadProvider(ProcessRuntimeFactory.java:28)
at org.drools.runtime.process.ProcessRuntimeFactory.getProcessRuntimeFactoryService(ProcessRuntimeFactory.java:21)
at org.drools.runtime.process.ProcessRuntimeFactory.newProcessRuntime(ProcessRuntimeFactory.java:12)
at org.drools.common.AbstractworkingMemory.createProcessRuntime(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:340)
at org.drools.common.AbstractworkingMemory.setKnowledgeRuntime(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1243) 
at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:117)
at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:109)
at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.newStatefulSession(ReteooRuleBase.java:403)
at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.newStatefulSession(ReteooRuleBase.java:383)
at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:176) 
at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:163)`